# Matrix calculator - pascal program - command line

Tags: parsing, matrix, input, pascal

I would like to make matrix calculator, but I struggle a little bit, how to make an input of the program. I have commands that user can use in calculator. Some takes 1 argument, 2 arguments or 3 arguments. I was inspired by program on this website http://www.ivank.net/blogspot/matrix_pascal/matrices.pas

But I don't really understand, how the input is made. Program from the website use parse, split procedures, but I don't know, how does it work. Does it exists some website, where it is good explained (Parse in Pascal)? I would like to really understand it.

This is, how it should looks like:

```
command: sum X Y
command: multiply X
command: transpose X
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sample which inspired you, all the calculation is realized by the 'procedure parse(command:String);'.
The first step consists to extract the command and all parameters by:

```
com := Split(command, ' ');
```

In your case, you will obtain for 'command: sum X Y':

```
Length(com) = 3
com[0] = 'sum'; com[1] = 'X'; com[2] = 'Y';
```

But, be carefull, the 'X' and 'Y' parameters shall not have  characters between numbers.